# d3 onerror default image with html tooltip tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, d3.js, onerror

I am making a tooltip with images and other data for a mouseover event in my D3 project. I would like to use a default image when my data images are missing. I am not able to get onerror to work with the html string I have written and I would be grateful if someone could take a look at it for me. I think my trouble iw with formatting of this string.

This is the relevant bit of code:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(50)
  div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);

  div.html('<img src="images/'+ d.properties.objectNumber +'.jpg" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src="images/00037631.jpg" style ="width:4em;" /> &nbsp;' + d.properties.name)

    //div.html('<img src="images/'+ d.properties.objectNumber +'.jpg" onError="this.src="images/ANMS0533[020].jpg" style ="width:4em;" /> &nbsp;' + d.properties.name)
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
})
```

My image shows up fine where it exists, but if the image is missing I get a no image icon and I would like to see a default image, or nothing.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: This might be caused by `onError` expecting a function.

Comment: Thank you for responding. So I can’t use on error here in the html like this? I am not sure how to use a function here. Are you able to help with sample code or point me to a resource that could help? Thanks again for taking the trouble to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably solve this problem like this, either use `id` or `class` on the uploaded img tag then select it using d3 and append on on error event to it.

```js
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(50)
  div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);

  div.html('<img id="loadingPic" src="images/'+ d.properties.objectNumber +'.jpg"/> &nbsp;' + d.properties.name)

d3.select("#loadingPic").on("error", function(){
  let el = d3.select(this);
  el.attr("src", "images/00037631.jpg").style("width", "4em");
  el.on("error", null);
})
    //div.html('<img src="images/'+ d.properties.objectNumber +'.jpg" onError="this.src="images/ANMS0533[020].jpg" style ="width:4em;" /> &nbsp;' + d.properties.name)
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The solution works perfectly for me. My attempts to write the function didn't get me anywhere so I really appreciate your help.